# Boas práticas para manter o código limpo

Tags: android

Desenvolvo em Android a poucos meses e uma coisa que notei é que quanto mais recursos uma tela tem, mais bagunçada o código fica!

### Como assim?

Imagine uma activity que possui Loading bar, varias ações que fazem chamadas assíncronas, etc.
o código-fonte fica cheio de classes e bem bagunçado, conhecem uma boa prática para agrupar essas classes em arquivos separados? Qualquer boa prática é bem vinda!

Comment: A orientação a objeto é a responsável por isso, crie objetos para o que precisar e modularize de acordo com a necessidade. Se o código está ficando muito grande é provável que poderia ter um encapsulamento diferente.

Comment: Não se preocupe tanto com isso não, a recomendação do Kyllopardium é boa, justamente para prevalecer a composição de objetos e delegação de responsabilidade a fim de evitar código monolíticos e "enrolados". Uma ideia é seccionar sua interface em `Fragments` e distribuir as responsabilidades entre eles. Outra sugestão é olhar projetos Android que sejam Open Source, no Github por exemplo. Um bom que eu recomendo é o `iosched`: https://github.com/google/iosched (O app do Google I/O).

Comment: Não é exatamente a resposta para a sua pergunta, mas experimente ler o livro Clean Code do Robert C. Martin. http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882 At.

Answer (score 2):

Eu utilizo a seguinte estrutura para gerenciar os pacotes e classes:

- *.activity - Grupo de classes que manipulam activitys.
- *.adapter - Grupo de classes que utilizam  adapters.
- *.broadcastreceiver - Grupo de classes que recebem sinais broadcast.
- *.db - Grupo de classes que manipulam banco de dados
- *.db.tables - Grupo de classes base das suas tabelas do banco de dados.
- *.fragments - Grupo de classes que manipulam fragments em seu projeto.
- *.service - Grupo de classes que geram services em seu programa.
- *.sync - Grupo de classes que utilizam asynctask ou outro tipo de sistema de sincronização.
- *.utilities - Grupo de classes auxiliares.

Você também pode criar pacotes de classes de acordo com sua necessidade. Utilize bastante o conceito de modularização de código. Além disso comente seu código, os comentários te ajudam na hora de se orientar.

Espero ter ajudado.